# Working with Multi-base Numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I wouldn't be surprised if there is an official term for what I am talking about, but I have never come across it. When I say `Multi-base` numbers, I mean a number where each digit is of a different base.

For example, lets take the number 111.

In this case, the first digit is base 3, the second digit is base 2, and the third digit is base 3.

So when converted to base 10 it would equal 10. To figure this out I simply started counting.

```
Base
323    

000    0
001    1
002    2
010    3
011    4
012    5
100    6
101    7
102    8
110    9
111   10
```

I figured out I can go from "multi-base" to base 10 with the following:

```
1 * Digit1 + Base-Digit1 * Digit2 + (Base-Digit1 * Base-Digit2) * Digit3
```

So in this case:

```
1 * 1 + 3 * 1 + (3 * 2) * 1
1 + 3 + 6 = 10
```

My questions are:

1. What is the correct way to mathematically write this formula?
2. How would I go from base 10 to "multi-base"?
3. Is there a term for these type of numbers?

Just for background info, I'm working on a program where the data can be modeled as a "multi-base number" and converting a base 10 number to a variable "multi-base number" will be useful.

Comment: Just as an observation, this sort of phenomenon occurs in the familiar setting of timekeeping:  there are 60 seconds in a minute, 60 minutes in an hour, 24 hours in a day, 7 days in a week.  So (using colons to separate places) 3 w : 4 d : 15 h : 45 m : 30 sec is a "multi-base" number in this sense.

Comment: These are sometimes called **generalised Cantor expansions**.  Google gives a few references.

Comment: I also came across the term [Mixed radix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix) to describe these numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I go from base 10 to "multi-base"?

From [mweiss](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/124095/mweiss)'s comment, you would have understood this. So, this is only  for completeness. Divide the number by the largest "base" (base$_{digit1}$ $\times$ base$_{digit2}$ in the given example). The quotient will be the left most digit. Divide the reminder by the next highest base. Keep doing till all bases are run out.

```
    6 | 8 | 1
    3 | 2 | 0
        2
```

reading downwards we get $102_{mixed-base} = 8_{10}$